# Comparing DateTime variable to a Date variable from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, date, datetime

I'm using sql server 2008 and trying to show a notification when a user's last login was earlier than the date of the last message added to the database.

I'm using `asp:panel` to show hide the notification text and it works just fine, but for some reason I can't figure out why the `Compare` method I'm using isn't returning the expected result.

For example, when I set the user login to `01/05/2013` and the most recent date in the database is `01/04/2013`, I expect the result to be a greater than zero int and escape the if condition. That, unfortunately, doesn't happen and the method always goes into the if condition.

I think it may have something to do with the `casting` from `Date` to `DateTime`; ideas, please?

```
DateTime userEntry = new DateTime(2012, 01, 05);
DateTime lastMsg = new DateTime();
lastMsg = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"]);
int compared = DateTime.Compare(userEntry, lastMsg);
if (compared < 0) { notification.Visible = true; }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say always goes into a loop..? do you have this code nested in a for loop that you are not showing here..?

Comment: What is the value you are getting in lastMsg ? Does it comply with the value in Database ?

Comment: DJ KRAZE - it goes into the IF condition every time i run it with different values that means it shouldn't go inside.

prthrokz = the value i'm getting into lastMsg is from a Date type column in an sql table converted to DateTime. i HOPE it works as it should. not sure how to check.

Comment: the value when you Debug compared is it -1 ...?

Comment: Also, DateTime.Compare returns a value less than 0 when first parameter is earlier than second parameter. From your description, it will not escape the if condition since 01/05 is not earlier than 01/04

Comment: What is the data type of your ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"] column of database.Is it varchar?

Comment: ridoy - the type is Date.
DJ KRAZE - i have no idea how to see variable value with visual studio 2012 , if you can explain how i'll really appreciate it.
prthrokz - it goes into the condition even if i change the login date to 01/01.

Comment: How are you running this code.. use F5 to step thru the code using the Debugger.. looking at the code without running it it will return -1 in your if statement.. you need to actually probably compare on something like the lstMsg.Year or something.. perhaps TimeStamp compare might work out better..

Comment: Can you just use the < <= instead of compare()..? here is something that will work             
if (userEntry <= lastMsg)
            {
               notification.Visible = true; ;
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that you are trying to compare "01/05/2013", yet, the code is generating a 2012 date:

```
DateTime userEntry = new DateTime(2012, 01, 05); // 2012 date
```

I suspect you really meant:

```
DateTime userEntry = new DateTime(2013, 01, 05); // 2013 date
```